# Reference (FK) user in administrator table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have 2 tables in the database: User and Administrator

When an administrator is registered, an entry in the User table is added, and inmediately after, I want reference this user in the Administrator table.

I'm using EF Core and the comments are the steps:

```
// Register user
this.context
    .Users
    .Add(new Entities.User()
    {
        Name = "Jhon",
    });

// Get the ID of the newly created user
int userId = this.context
    .Users
    .Select(_ => _.Id ????)

// Reference the user created in the Administrator table
this.context
    .Administradors
    .Add(new Entities.Administrator()
    {
        UserId = userId
    });
```

I need both tables because the administrator has fields that the user no.

Comment: Don't link through ID, link through entity by moving the objects outside the Add methods

Comment: I don't understand. What are you meaning with 'moving objects outside Add method' ?

Comment: `var user = new Entities.User(); var admin = new Entities.Administrator(); admin.User = user; context.Users.Add(user); context.administrators.Add(admin);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the newly created user in a variable. Then save the changes, EF will update the ID

```
var user = new Entities.User { Name = "John" };
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();

// Reference the user created in the Administrator table
context.Administradors.Add(new Entities.Administrator { UserId = user.Id });
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, a better alternative is to use the navigation property instead of using the ID.

```
var user = new Entities.User { Name = "John" };
context.Users.Add(user);

// Reference the user created in the Administrator table
context.Administradors.Add(new Entities.Administrator { User = user });

context.SaveChanges();
```

This requires ony one `SaveChanges()`.

EF is smart enough to make the fixup. I.e., if you work with the ID, EF will update the navigation property when doing the `SaveChanges()`. If you work with the navigation property, EF will update the ID when doing the `SaveChanges()`.